# WIN10 -Unable to run MySql server after installation - 5.7

Tags: mysql

I previously had MySql 5.7 installed and it worked fine.  I last used it 3-5 months ago.  When trying to run the server/daemon I ran into the following error:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin>mysqld
mysqld: Can't change dir to 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\data\' (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
2017-10-09T23:44:49.897072Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2017-10-09T23:44:49.897072Z 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
2017-10-09T23:44:49.898074Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.19) starting as process 39932 ...
2017-10-09T23:44:49.901585Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\data\MSI.lower-test
2017-10-09T23:44:49.901585Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\data\MSI.lower-test
2017-10-09T23:44:49.902588Z 0 [ERROR] failed to set datadir to C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\data\
2017-10-09T23:44:49.903592Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2017-10-09T23:44:49.904597Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2017-10-09T23:44:49.905096Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

I uninstalled all MYSQL programs via Control Panel and then reinstalled from the site but I still receive the exact same error messages.  Does anyone have any advice for what to do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to create a database so I can learn how to hook up a django app to a custom mysql database and am having issues.  I'll leave the question in case someone who knows can answer but I'll also post on the other sites.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A few potential issues:

1. In your my.ini file, remove the trailing `\` from the datadir variable, and change the remaining final `\` to `/`. You path will look like `...\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7/data`
2. Whatever user you are running mysqld as may not have permissions on C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\data. If you installed as administrator, try running command prompt as administrator. If there is a service registered for MySQL, open up `services.msc` and start it from there.